# How to access object member variable when calling an object method through google.maps.event.addDomListener

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm working with the google-maps javascript v.3 API. I'm just showing a smart pall of the code here, which I think is the only part that is relevant for my question.

I don't understand why the member variables of the object `GMaps` seem to dissapear when calling gmaps.initMap as follows `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', gmaps.initMap);`

I've implemented the function `GMaps.test` to see if the member variable `GMaps.LATIDX` is correctly alerted, this indeed works as expected. However when I try to alert the same member variable in the function `GMaps.initMap`, called through`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', gmaps.initMap);`, then an "undefined" is alerted, I don't understand why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>

var GMaps = function() {
    this.map = null;
    // constants
    this.LATIDX = 0; // 2d array index constant (latitude index)
    this.LNGIDX = 1; // 2d array index constant (longtitude index)

    this.test = function() {
        alert(this.LATIDX); // THIS ALERTS 0 AS EXPECTED
    }

    this.initMap = function(aActor, aLatLngCoord, aLatLngCenter) {
        alert(this.LATIDX); // THIS ALERTS "undefined", I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY.
    }
 }
</script>

gmaps = new GMaps();
gmaps.test();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', gmaps.initMap);

</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `addDomListener`/`addListener` the API will execute the callback in the context of the object  the listener has been applied to(in your code it's `window`) , `this` will point to this object.

To change the context  use bind(or apply) and use the desired object(`gmaps`) as first argument:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 
                                 'load', 
                                 function(){
                                   gmaps.initMap.call(gmaps);
                                 });
```

When the function is a method of a particular object, as in your code, it's sufficient to use a callback which executes the desired function(object-method), then you don't need to change the context:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 
                                 'load', 
                                 function(){//context is window
                                   gmaps.initMap();//context is gmaps
                                 });
```